# Cannot enable PHP PDO MSSQL on Windows

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, iis, pdo

I have PHP 5.3 installed on my Windows laptop, but cannot get the PHP PDO extension for MSSQL to work. PHP is running with IIS 8.5. My PHP info page shows some configuration options that appear to be disabling PDO for MSSQL. I cannot figure out how to re-compile PHP on Windows so I can remove these options. Below is the configure command shown on the PHP info page:

```
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" 
    "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" 
    "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" 
    "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" 
    "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" 
    "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" 
    "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" 
    "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze"
```

After restarting IIS my PHP info page still does not have MSSQL shown under the PDO section. I have already copied the correct extension files in place and edited the php.ini file to enable the  extension (not sure if this is including the correct DLL):

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
```